# start.aspx redirecting in Minimal Download Strategy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, minimal-download-strategy

EDIT: Turns out there is probably an issue with the page. This exact problem is described here with possible causes: https://threewill.com/working-with-and-around-sharepoint-2013s-minimal-download-strategy/

I believe start.aspx is required for MDS to be able to pick up a diff between two pages, however the clients' browsers are being redirected to the page without it, so they aren't able to see the benefits.

E.g. client hits this page:

```
/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//Pages/Home.aspx
```

After 2 seconds, they're redirected to this page:

```
/Pages/Home.aspx
```

Trying to get rid of that redirect so that MDS can do its magic

Comment: Did you find what was the reason of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Minimal Download Strategy does not work if you have SharePoint Publishing feature activated. This was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the feature has been deactivated. Navigate to Site Settings - > Manage Site Features and activate the feature **Minimal download strategy**

Comment: It's activated, turns out there is some failure with MDS. Editing my question